Why is this deadlock happening?
I'm hoping someone might be able to shed some light on why my deadlock problem is occurring.
I'm running on Microsoft SQL Server 2022
I'm getting a deadlock when two threads are running an insert and an update at the same time on the same table.
Something else I'm not sure I understand is I'm only inserting one new row into the table so I'm confused as to why it tries to do an IX lock multiple pages?
If someone could shed some light on to why it's happening with an update and an insert running at the same time that would be great!

The table being inserted / updated:
CREATE TABLE [Config].[Epr_Document](
    [Epr_Document_Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Type_Id] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Document_Date] [DATETIME2](3) NOT NULL,
    [Document_Version] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Unique_Id] [VARCHAR](256) NOT NULL,
    [Document_Id] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Patient_No_Id] [VARCHAR](32) NOT NULL,
    [Calculated_Version] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Is_Deleted] [BIT] NOT NULL,
    [Created_On] [DATETIME2](0) NULL,
    [Is_Latest_Version] [BIT] NULL,
    [Application_Instance_Id] [INT] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Epr_Document] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Epr_Document_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF, DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

It has two indexes on it:
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_document_version_key] ON [Config].[Epr_Document]
(
    [Type_Id] ASC,
    [Patient_No_Id] ASC,
    [Unique_Id] ASC,
    [Document_Id] ASC,
    [Document_Date] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF, DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_latest_version] ON [Config].[Epr_Document]
(
    [Type_Id] ASC,
    [Is_Latest_Version] ASC,
    [Is_Deleted] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF, DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

The insert query:
if not exists (
    select 1 
    from [Config].[Epr_Document]
    where 
        --document
        [Type_Id] = @Type_Id
        and Patient_No_Id = @Patient_No_Id
        and Unique_Id = @Unique_Id
        --version
        and Document_Id = @Document_Id
        and Document_Date = @Document_Date
)
begin 
    INSERT INTO [Config].[Epr_Document] (
        --[Epr_Document_Id] IDENTITY
        [Type_Id]
        , [Document_Date]
        , [Document_Version]
        , [Unique_Id]
        , [Document_Id]
        , [Patient_No_Id]
        , [Calculated_Version]
        , [Is_Deleted]
        , [Is_Latest_Version]
        , [Created_On]
        , [Application_Instance_Id]
    )
    select 
        @Type_Id as [Type_Id]
        , @Document_Date as [Document_Date]
        , @Document_Version as [Document_Version]
        , @Unique_Id as [Unique_Id]
        , @Document_Id as [Document_Id]
        , @Patient_No_Id as [Patient_No_Id]
        , 0 as [Calculated_Version]
        , 0 as [Is_Deleted]
        , 0 as [Is_Latest_Version]
        , getdate() as [Created_On]
        , @Application_Instance_Id as [Application_Instance_Id]
end

The update query
UPDATE d
SET d.Is_Deleted = 1 
    ,d.Application_Instance_Id = @Application_Instance_Id
from [Config].[Epr_Document] as d
join [Config].[Temporary_Data_Deleted_Documents] as del
    on d.[Type_Id] = del.[Type_Id]
    and d.Document_Id = del.Document_Id
WHERE d.[Type_Id] = @Type_Id


As a side note, without appropriate locking your INSERT could end up with a race condition: 1. Connection 1 checks if the row exists; it doesn't. 2. Connection 2 checks the (same) row exists; it doesn't. 3. Connection 1 inserts the row. 4. Connection 2 inserts the (same) row. Why not have the NOT EXISTS in the WHERE of the INSERT's SELECT?
